# Almost equal random variables

Tags: measure-theory

$\frac{|X-Y|}{1 + |X-Y|}$ is almost surely equal to 0 if and only if $X$ is almost surely equal to $Y$. How to prove this?

It seems obvious since $|X - Y|$ is positive if and only if $\frac{|X-Y|}{1 + |X-Y|}$ is positive, so the sets which make them positive are equal and since one of them is a null set per assumption, so is the other, but is it correct? How to write it formally?

Answer (score 1):

From the fact that for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$: $$\frac{\left|x-y\right|}{1+\left|x-y\right|}=0\iff x=y$$
follows directly that:

$$\left\{ \omega\in\Omega\mid\frac{\left|X\left(\omega\right)-Y\left(\omega\right)\right|}{1+\left|X\left(\omega\right)-Y\left(\omega\right)\right|}=0\right\} =\left\{ \omega\in\Omega\mid X\left(\omega\right)=Y\left(\omega\right)\right\}$$
or shorter:

$$\left\{ \frac{\left|X-Y\right|}{1+\left|X-Y\right|}=0\right\} =\left\{ X=Y\right\}$$

That implies that: $$\Pr\left(\frac{\left|X-Y\right|}{1+\left|X-Y\right|}=0\right)=\Pr\left(X=Y\right)$$
and consequently:

$$\Pr\left(\frac{\left|X-Y\right|}{1+\left|X-Y\right|}=0\right)=1\iff\Pr\left(X=Y\right)=1$$

In words:$$\frac{\left|X-Y\right|}{1+\left|X-Y\right|}=0\text{ almost surely if and only if }X=Y\text{ almost surely}$$